# Help in deciding if this complex function is bounded

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, gamma-function

Let $a \neq 0\in \mathbb{C}$ and consider the function
$$f(z) = \frac{a^{z}}{\Gamma(z+1)}.$$

It is true that $f$ is bounded in every  compact set contained in $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{-1,-2,-3,-4,\dots\}$ ?

Observation: In the calculation of $a^z$ i'm considering only the principal argument.

Comment: Why wouldn't it be? It's continuous so bounded on compacts (note that at the poles of $\Gamma$ it is zero so the restriction is not necessary); the only problem would come at zeroes of the denominator, but gamma doesn't have any...

Comment: Thank you, I thought that I would have problem in the continuity of the gamma function, I'm happy to know that it's not the case. So, I can use known property that continuous functions on compact sets are bounded.